# PyQt Button Selection

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I have a PyQt GUI set up that has a selection of QPushButtons and a QLineEdit text box (among other things). The text box is set up so as to call a function upon returnPressed(). My problem is that when I click on the text box and put in text, one of the buttons becomes selected which means that when I press enter in the text box it activates both the button and the text box function.

Is there a way around this? Some way to stop any buttons from being selected while the text box is being edited?

The code is fairly long so I can't add it here but if there are any questions regarding layout or anything that may be relevant, please ask.

Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes selected"? And _how_ does the button "become selected"? Have you got a handler connected to a text-change signal or something?

Comment: It becomes highlighted. There's nothing explicit in my code connected to the text box except for the returnPressed connecting to a function call. 
The button becomes highlighted as soon as I click on the text box

Comment: @user3011077 post some sections of your code, for example the points where the controls are created, any bindings etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question and comments, I'm guessing that the buttons and line-edit are in a QDialog, and that the selection/highlighting occurs due to the [default](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#default-prop)/[autoDefault](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) property of buttons.

Normally, these properties will be set to False, but in a QDialog they are automatically set to True. The button that is the current default gets an additional frame drawn around it (even when it doesn't have the keyboard focus), and is activated whenever the return key is pressed.

You can of course prevent this behaviour by simply doing:

```
button.setDefault(False)
button.setAutoDefault(False)
```

for each button in the dialog.